# Message to create different types of DNS records

Tags: c++, linux, dns

For work i am going to use use DNS records between two servers using a software made by the company. Mostly SRV, NAPTR and A records.

To propagate the information i have to create a new type of message which is going to be sent by a function in our software managing all messages. 
Instead of creating 3 types of messages "SRv" "NAPTR "A" i thought about creating only one kind - general for all DNS records - with a part of the message dedicated to the type; NAPTR, A, SRV, MX etc...

I would like to have advice for the fields needed in this message, for example which fields are common for each DNS record type to include them in all messages, and which fields are specials for each records ? (Maybe creating a Data field in the message for additionnal informations specific for each type (prefix and protocol for NAPTR for example))

Actually for NAPTR (only one i did) i have various variables like TTL, zone, that i receive.
And i put every one in a stream and update it with :

```
system("nsupdate update.txt")
```

the file filled with the oss looks like this:

```
update add test.zone 60 NAPTR 10 100 "S" "SIP+D2T" "" _sip._tcp.zone.
send
```

But i would like to have a more general message which adapts for various DNS records if someday i need new ones.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Each resource type is different. You can not find a common subset, besides the class and the TTL. For example the target of a `A` record is an IP address and the target of a `NS` is an hostname, so they are orthogonal.

Comment: Yes, since the post of the question i managed to get informations in the RFC documents and i solved my problem. Thank you still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem i created one message subdivised in two part, header and body. The header has all the common infos of  the RR, like TTL, domain, Class, Type, and in function of the type i create a "length of data" and "data" field for each RR. For example NAPTR got data field with others fields in it, like Weight, Priority etc...
I did not found any better idea to factorise the informations.